# BizTalk WCF-WebHttp adapter Client Certificate not found

Tags: ssl, biztalk, client-certificates, wcf-web-api, biztalk-2016

When configuring the WCF-WebHttp security tab, I have set Security Mode to `Transport`, Client Credential type to `Certificate`.

When I go to browse for Client Cert, it comes up with the only options being `Current User/My Store` instead of `Local Machine/Address Book`. So, to see what happens, I imported my cert into the `Current User/My Store`. This worked fine and I imported the same cert into the `Service Certificate` tab. When a message is processed through the send port, an error like so occurs:

> Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'CurrentUser', FindType 'FindByThumbprint', FindValue 'EF742FBAF0A13A7BEA859DC573308D52F0611CDB'.

When it tries to do a GET to the REST service we are trying to consume.

The configuration I'm using looks like so:

[image]

I'm assuming that since the BizTalk service is not running as myself, it can't find the client cert. I've also imported the cert into the `Local Computer/Personal` store to see if that helps, to no avail.

My question is, how can I get the correct client cert selected through the BizTalk interface? Is there a way to specify it in the Outbound Message Headers perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Certificate Usage Scenarios for the WCF Send Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/installing-certificates-for-the-wcf-adapters#certificate-usage-scenarios-for-the-wcf-send-ports)

> Log on to each computer running BizTalk Server that will host the send ports **as each host instance service account**, and import the client certificate to the Current User \ Personal (My) store.

You can also do this by just launching the MMC as the BizTalk Service Account user.

Comment: Thanks, I was just coming back to say I actually read the docs and saw this part. It looks like it worked, but now I'm getting the `Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority` error, but that's a different question :)